# `heroku pg:psql` doesnt work but psql works

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Note: I'm on windows.

After installing postgreSQL in my computer trying to use `heroku pg:psql` gives me this error:

`--> Connecting to postgresql-defined-56809
 !    The local psql command could not be located. For help installing psql, see
 !    https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#local-setup`

The `psql` command works and `psql --version` returns the same version that my database uses on heroku as returned by `heroku pg:info`.

I have followed the instructions in that link and it still doesn't work (well I did that from the beginning). I even restarted my computer but it still doesn't work.

Edit: found that `psql` runs in powershell but not in cmd

Answer (score 0):

Okay so after trying to set up the PATH from cmd I think I messed something up and the `heroku` command didnt work anymore and I reinstalled heroku and now everything works fine. What a waste of time.